# Authentication challenge in Webview component of React Native

Tags: webview, react-native

I am trying to load a URL in react native webview which needs credentials. Normally when we open this URL in a browser like Safari and Chrome, it give us a popup to enter the credentials. Not sure how to handle it in React-Native?

Answer (score 1):

We require LinkedIn authentication for our React Native application, we couldn't find a way to work with the `WebView` component.

This **may** very well be possible, however, I will highlight what solution we came up with. These steps are for an iOS React Native app, steps will differ for Android but the concept is the same. This also does require some server configuration.

We created a URL Type. In XCode, select your project and click on the `Info` tab. Scroll to the bottom to see **URL Types**. Fill in the `identifier` and `URL Schemes`. Remember what you've set for the `URL Schemes`. For this example, we will use `myscheme`.

When the app opens, we use `Linking` to open up the URL in Safari.

```
Linking.openURL('https://foo.bar');
```

The User could then log in via the website, once logged in, you can redirect your User back to.

```
myscheme://name=Dan
```

The `myscheme` matching the `URL Scheme` you entered within Xcode. As long as you have your application installed and the scheme matches then your app will open.

You can add any payload of information after `://`.

In your React application, you can register

```
componentWillMount() {
  Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  Linking.removeEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
}

handleOpenURL = (event) => {
  const { url } = event;
  if (url.startsWith('myscheme://')) {
    // do something with your data.
  }
};
```

Comment: This seems to be a fantastic workaround but sadly I do not have server side access as I am trying to open a intranet URL on my react-native app and the link supports ADFS authentication.